How come ΔG∘ is related to the equilibrium constant?
As I understand it, standard state is when the pressure of a gas is 1 bar and quantity 1 mol.
Now the following relation holds:
$$\Delta G^\circ=-RT \ln(K)$$
Suppose I declare a new standard state to be when pressure of a gas is 2 bars and quantity 1.5 mol. Would the relation still hold? Rephrased, my question is: how come equilibrium of a reaction is related to a change at a (seemingly arbitrary) standard state?

A standard state is a convention decided on to allow communication. If you look up the equation relating free energy charge, equilibrium constant and actual conditions you will find new definitions on an arbitrary basis are not helpful [Biochemistry is an example of a helpful nonarbitrary change]. The standard states of activities for a gas are a fugacity[pressure] of 1.; a pure substance a mole fraction of 1.. These are independent of the amount

The relationship still would hold. You would have a different numerical value of K because its definition is linked to the definition of the standard state as well. One example is biochemistry, where the pH of the standard state is 7 rather than 0 (among other, more subtle differences).
There are some mistakes in your definition of standard state which I am not addressing for brevity.
